# Ввод и вычисление произведения элементов массива

Tags: c++, массивы

> Найти произведение элементов одномерного массива, состоящего из N
> элементов. Размер массива и его элементы вводятся с клавиатуры.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a, mul;
    cin >> a;
    const int size = a;
    int arr[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        mul *= arr[i];
    }
    cout << mul;
}
```

Comment: Грешил на массивы, а `mul` инициализировать чем-нибудь забыл...

Comment: инициализируй `mul = 1;`

Answer (score 7):

Ну какая же это константа? Вернее, константа - только в том смысле, что `size` не будет изменяться, но во время компиляции эта константа неизвестна.

```
const int size = a;
```

Соответственно, это тоже неверно - в С++ размер массива должен быть известен во время компиляции:

```
int arr[size];
```

`mul` надо инициализировать - вы начинаете множить мусор. Да и в `int` результат вряд ли поместится без переполнения.

Так что...

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int * arr = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> arr[i];
double mul = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    mul *= arr[i];
cout << mul;
```

Только вот смотрите - можно два цикла объединить в один, так?

```
double mul = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
    mul *= arr[i];
}
```

Но тогда встает вопрос - а зачем нам вообще массив? и мы получаем (еще и одну переменную экономим...)

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    double mul = 1;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
    {
        cin >> n;
        mul *= n;
    }
    cout << mul;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как то так :

```
int main() {
    int size = 0;
    double mul = 1;
    cin >> size;
    int * arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
        mul *= arr[i];
    }
    cout << mul;
    return 0;
}
```